How to redirect wallet native app from a browser dapp?
We would like to create a feature that would allow a user to press the buy button on a browser dapp(not native dapp) and it would switch to a wallet app such as metamask to sign and issue the transaction. Is it possible?
Thank you.

You need to do it in two stages

Connect wallet (using WalletConnect)
Issue payment request (using JSON-RPC API eth_sendTransaction or its wrapper)

